# Using semaphores to return an image from Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, parse-platform

I would like to be able to retrieve an image from parse like this:

```
-(UIImage *) image {

   __block NSData * imageData;
   dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

     [self.imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        imageData = data;
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
     }];

     dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
     return [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

But since the block is executed on the mail thread and the semaphore is waiting on the main thread, the block is never executed. How can I redo my code? I need to able to return an image without a completionBlock since this method is called by a library I use.

Comment: you want to load image from the background, then update in the main thread?

Comment: I just want the return statement to execute after imageData has been set. Parse loads the data in the background but then calls the block on the main thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion block runs on the main thread... which is blocked waiting for your semaphore. You have a deadlock here. Have you considered using the synchronous getData in a background thread to fetch the information instead?

Comment: I don't want it to run on the main thread. It should run on whatever thread the function is called on. Can I do that?

Comment: Yes. Use getData for that.

Comment: If was hoping to encapsulate the dispatch_async in this method. But I guess I have to use getData.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the GCD, to parse and load in the background, then use the image in the main thread.
The code maybe like followings:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage *image = nil;
        __block NSData *imageData;
        [self.imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            imageData = data;
        }];
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (image) {
                return image; // use your image here.
            } 
        });

    });
```